# Ubuntu server 16.04 python3 periodically makes a call to rubay.canonical.com

Tags: 16.04, firewall, python3

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server. Periodically I see python3 making requests to:

```
IP: 91.189.95.15
Port: 80
Hostname: rubay.canonical.com
```

This is unnecessary and a waste for this server. Where is this configured so I can stop it?

Comment: same here!! :-|

Answer (score 4):

I found this question while reviewing firewall logs.

Upon investigation, this is a check to see if there has been a release upgrade, which is then presented as part of the "Welcome to Ubuntu..." message.

It fetches the URI configured in /etc/update-manager/meta-release.

On the system I'm looking at it is triggered as part of the user login process by /etc/update-motd.d/91-release-upgrade, but only if is more than 24 hours since the previous fetch.